# Ghostscript to convert .jpeg to .pdf

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

Below is the command I am trying to convert from .jpeg to .pdf

gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=E:\temp\testPDF1.pdf "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c (E:/temp/test3.jpeg) viewJPEG

I am getting below error.

Error: /undefined in 
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-

- 2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fa
  lse   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nost
  ringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
  Dictionary stack:
  --dict:1180/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--
  Current allocation mode is local
  Last OS error: No such file or directory
  GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 1):

The viewjpeg.ps program accesses the JPEG file on disk and attempts to open it.

Because of security vulnerabilities recent versions of Ghostscript now run with -dSAFER as the default, and that disables the PostScript interpreter's ability to open/read/write/delete files on disk. I'd have expected an invalidaccess error, but I'm reasonably confident this will be the source of the problem.

You can either use `-dNOSAFER` (**NOT** recommended) or you can specify that the file is permitted to be accessed (for reading) using `--permit-file_read=E:/temp`.

This is all documented [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.53.0/Use.htm#Other_parameters) under -dSAFER. Since you are using Windows please take note of the fact that the path matching for the --permit switches is case-sensitive **even on Windows**.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ken. I am still getting error as below .
Error: /undefinedfilename in (E:/temp/test3.jpeg)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fa
lse   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1181/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:81/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: what is the format to give file path. I am giving as  :
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=E:\temp\testPDF1.pdf  -dNOSAFER "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\lib\viewjpeg.ps" --permit-file_all E:/temp/test3.jpeg viewJPEG

Comment: is this right format ? --permit-file_all E:/temp/test3.jpeg viewJPEG

Comment: undefinedfilename means that the file/path doesn't exist. You appear to be using an elderly version of Ghostscript (9.10, which I missed in the original post) so you can forget the SAFER stuff and --permit-file switches won't work. Your original command is probably OK but you may need to put the (E:/temp/test3.jpeg) viewJPEG inside speech marks "". NB you can forget AutoRotatePages since it works on text and JPEG images don't contain text. You should check the path and filename, it seems like there's a problem there.

Comment: BTW, with -dNOSAFER you don't need any --permit-file-read=___ or --permit-file-all=___, but the problem is that " --permit-file_all E:/temp/test3.jpeg" is not correct. It should be " --permit-file_all=E:/temp/test3.jpeg" (an '=' not a <space> between the parameter and its value).

Answer (score 1):

Below command worked for me.

gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -sOutputFile=E:\temp\testPDF4.pdf "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c "(E:/temp/test3.jpg) <</PageSize 2 index viewJPEGgetsize 2 array astore>> setpagedevice viewJPEG"

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set it up as a batch file (this is on windows), but you need to have double backslash on the input file path for the viewJPEG command, otherwise you get the same sort of error as above. It also requires -dNOSAFER as @KenS mentioned (or implement the --permit-read ).

I use the following batch script to convert all the jpgs in a directory where the script resides. You can probably use this and add your page rotation switch where required.

```
rem Convert JPG to a PDF
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set path=C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.01.1\lib;C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.01.1\bin;%path%

FOR %%A IN ((*.jpg;*.jpeg) DO (
set outfile="%%~dpnA.pdf"
set "infile=%%~dpnxA"
set "infile=!infile:\=\\!"

echo !outfile!
echo !infile!

gswin64c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=!outfile! viewjpeg.ps -c "(!infile!) viewJPEG showpage"
)
```

The line `set "infile=!infile:\=\\!"` doubles your backslash.

Answer (score -1):

Just for one file, I hope this command can help you:

```
C:\docs\car\apps\gs\bin\gswin64c -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOPAUSE DNOSAFER -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=foo.pdf "\apps\gs\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c "(asseg00.jpg) viewJPEG"
```